# jQuery Animation Not-Actioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am writing a small jQuery function which will animate a slide-in & fade-in from the left effect on a menu when a div is clicked. I have included the script for the jQuery library and JS lint is not pulling up any grammar errors. Any help would be appreciated!

**Notes:**
My menu starts off-screen set by a margin-left: -100% and opacity: 0 and then is animated onto the screen using margin: 0 and opacity: 1. See below. I use the pseudo-class *visible* to keep track of whether the menu has been animated onto the screen or not.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="menu-button" class="pull-left">
    <p>&#8594; Menu &#8592;</p>
</div>

<ul id="blockmenu">
    <li class="menuitem">
        <a href="#">
            <p>Menu item 1</p>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $('#menu-button').click(function() {
        if ($('#blockmenu').hasClass('visible')) {
            $('#blockmenu').animate({
                margin: '0 0 0 -100%',
                opacity: '0'
            });
            $('#blockmenu').removeClass('visible');
        }
        else {
           $('#blockmenu').animate({
                margin: '0',
                opacity: '1'
            });
            $('#blockmenu').addClass('visible');
        }
    });
})
```

**CSS for good measure:**

```
#blockmenu {
    background-color: rgba(225,225,225,0.1);
    bottom: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 3em 4em 3em 4em;
    margin: 0 0 0 -100%;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999999;
}
```

Regards,

Finn

Comment: You can't animate `margin: '0 0 0 -100%'`, it's simply not a value that jQuery understands and can animate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you include [the jQuery library](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js) in your code, it works as expected.

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
$(function() {
    $('#menu-button').click(function() {
        if ($('#blockmenu').hasClass('visible')) {
            $('#blockmenu').animate({
                margin: '0 0 0 -100%',
                opacity: '0'
            });
            $('#blockmenu').removeClass('visible');
        }
        else {
           $('#blockmenu').animate({
                margin: '0',
                opacity: '1'
            });
            $('#blockmenu').addClass('visible');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#blockmenu {
    background-color: rgba(225,225,225,0.1);
    bottom: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 3em 4em 3em 4em;
    margin: 0 0 0 -100%;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999999;
}
```

```html
<!-- INCLUDE JQUERY LIBRARY! -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="menu-button" class="pull-left">
    <p>&#8594; Menu &#8592;</p>
</div>

<ul id="blockmenu">
    <li class="menuitem">
        <a href="#">
            <p>Menu item 1</p>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[Learn more](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp)

Comment: It's really bizarre because I have the library included in the header of my website, and yet, nothing.

Comment: @FinnLeSueur You might be a victim of jQuery conflict, if you are using multiple JS libraries that use the `$` symbol.

Comment: That would make a lot of sense, but I only have the one library imported using the exact same script as you used above.

Comment: Got it! Some z-indices got confused and my button was hiding behind a semi-transparent layer. Thanks :)